Kernelization For Odd Cycle Transversal Problem on Perfect Graphs
This problem appears as exercise 2.33 in https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~malcin/book/parameterized-algorithms.pdf (page 48). A perfect graph $G$ is bipartite if and only if it contains no triangle graphs. Then, the goal is to hit all of these triangle subgraphs. So the problem reduces to the 3-hitting-set problem. Then, for kernelization, we can exhaustively apply the sunflower lemma, that is, find $k+2$ sets, and delete one of them. After exhaustively applying the lemma, we will have a kernel of $\mathcal{O}(k^3)$ sets, however the problem asks for a $\mathcal{O}(k^2)$ kernel. I think before the sunflower lemma, there is another kernel that reduces the size of the sets to $\leq 2$, but I am not sure how.

Given the context of this exercise, maybe this is a typo. Others can confirm this. Although this paper claims for an $O(k^{d-1})$ kernel for the $d$-hitting set probelm.
